# Вывод данных за неделю в sqllite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Пишу на python одну вещь. Но дело не в этом.

```py
async def get_stat_day():
    """Статистика за день"""
    async with aiosqlite.connect(db_url) as db:
        async with db.execute("select count(distinct(user_id)) from statistics where add_date like ?", (f"%{datetime.date.today()}%",)) as cursor:    
            res = await cursor.fetchone()
            print(f"Статистика за день - {res[0]} пользователей просмотрено")
```

Мне нужно это функцию переделать так, чтобы вывести данные за неделю(7 дней включая текущий). Не могу понять как. Нужна помощь.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289680/difference-between-2-dates-in-sqlite

Answer (score 1):

Уже сам разобрался. В принципе было изначально понятно как. Но из-за того что у меня дата хранилась в определенном формате то не работало. Сейчас работает.Спасибо

Моя реализация получилась такая

````
    """Статистика за неделю"""
    today = datetime.date.today() 
    week_ago = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
    async with aiosqlite.connect(db_url) as db:
        async with db.execute("select acc_name, count(distinct(user_id)) from statistics where add_date between ? and ? group by acc_name",(week_ago, today) ) as cursor:    
            rows = await cursor.fetchall()
            print(f"Статистика за неделю\n")
            for row in rows:
                print(f"Аккаунт: {row[0]} - {row[1]} пользовател(я/ей)")```
````

Comment: Если разобрались, то поделитесь ответом с другими участниками сообщества, возможно через 10 лет кто-то наткнётся на ваш вопрос и сможет решить похожую проблему

Comment: Добавил в сообщении выше